# SQL select with double conditions

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to select the `parent_ids` that have both status = pending & processing, or the `parent_ids` who have both status = canceled and processing. grouped by `parent_id`.

I only manage to get `parent_ids` that have either pending, processing, or canceled as status which is not what I need. I need the double conditions.

I've tried something similar to:

```
select parent_id, status from tableName
where status = ('processing' and 'pending')
or status = ('processing' and 'canceled') group by parent_id
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```sql
SELECT parent_id
FROM tableName 
GROUP BY parent_id
HAVING SUM(status = 'processing')
   AND SUM(status IN ('pending', 'cancelling'));
```

The query checks does for particular `parent_id` a row (at least one) with 'processing' and a row with 'pending'/'cancelling' (any of) exists.

Alternatively you may use

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT parent_id
FROM tableName t1
JOIN tableName t2 USING (parent_id)
WHERE t1.status = 'processing'
  AND t2.status IN ('pending', 'cancelling');
```

This query do the same but in another form.

One more alternative:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT parent_id
FROM tableName t1
WHERE status = 'processing'
  AND EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
               FROM tableName t2
               WHERE t1.parent_id = t2.parent_id
                 AND t2.status IN ('pending', 'cancelling') );
```